# Android Game Developement Several scenes

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview

I am building a game for android using Canvas for 2D Graphics. The way I did it so far is I have a `GameView` (`SurfaceView`) which has a `GameLoop` that calls its `onDraw()` method.

Now for each Scene I extended the `GameView` and for the `MainMenu` for example I draw all the Buttons & Backgrounds. When I click a Button I will determine what to do next in the MainScene (extending GameView) onTouchEvent. Let's say I click the Settings Button, then I will start a new Activity which contains only a new Scene (another Scene extending the GameView).

So for each Scene I have a new `Activity` just containing an Extension of the GameView which includes a `GameLoop` to draw 20/30 times per second. And in the `onTouchEvents` I will either start a new activity / finish an activity or do something else.

MainActivity (MainScene ) -> SettingsActivity(SettingsScene) or StoreActivity(StoreScene) etc.
Is that a correct way to do it? Or is it inefficient?

I couldn't find tutorials or a lot to read about multi scene game applications using canvas.

Comment: The right answer is often, "use an open-source 2D game engine".  I would like to point out that, if you're rendering to the Canvas you get from `onDraw()`, you're probably drawing on the View rather than on the Surface, and there's no point using a SurfaceView.  Just use a custom view -- http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html .  Or just use GLES; simple GLSurfaceView-based example here: https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/ .

Answer (score 1):

Actually launch new Activity for each scene is OK when you are developing standard Android apps. It would be ok for simple games or when you don't want to manually manage resources(Activity will be destroyed when system needs resources and will be recreated when needed). In this approach, you don't have full control on Scene transitions and you'll need to reinit some things for each activity that could be inited once for the entire game.

If you want to make scene transitions a faster and more efficient you have at least 3 more variants.

1. Fragments. Instead off launching activity for every scene you could replace Fragments that contains a view of your scene. In this approach you have more control on transitions and fragments state.
2. Views. Instead of replacement fragments you could replace views in the same way, using Frame layout as container for example.
3. Scene drawers. Instead of replacing views you could just replace Drawer class in your view. For example, you could create an interface Scene that contains method draw(Canvas, args...) and make all your scenes implement it. After that you could just replace scene you want to draw inside View.

Any way i prefer to use http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ for simple android games. Main benefit is you can run your game on your desktop to test instead of waiting for deployment on device.